# jQuery's .each() in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the alternative way of doing something like

```
$(".myElement").each(function(){ 
    //function
});
```

in plain Javascript?

Comment: Having an ID was a mistake on my part, I've edited it to be a class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will iterate all `div`s in your current document. You can replace `document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')` etc. and do something with their `attributes` and `values`

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    doSomething(elements[i]);
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/allenski/p7w5btLa/

Answer (score 3):

```
$(#myElement)
```

You are trying to iterate over a `id` selector. **ID** has to be unique in a HTML page.

If it's a `class or element` tags you want to iterate over you can use a `for` loop.

```
var $elems = $('.someClass');
for(var i=0; i< $elems.length; i++ ) {

     // $elems[i] --> Gives you a `DOM` element
     // $elems.eq(i) --> Gives you a `jQuery` object
}
```

**Vanilla Javascript**

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('someClass');

for(var i=0;i< elems.length;i ++) {
    elem[i] // Based on index
}
```

`getElementsByTagName` if you want to iterate over specific tags.

`getElementsByName` - get the elements based on name attribute.

You can also use `document.querySelectorAll` to get a list of objects and iterate over them.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.someClass')
  for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i] // Give you DOM object
  }
```

Comment: By putting the $(".someClass") in the `for`, you are recalculating it at every cycle of the for.

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = $(something);

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    // do something with el[i] or more often with $(el[i])
}
```

`el` is a pseudo-array (or array-like Object) that has a `length` and elements accessible with the `[]` operator in the range `0...length-1`. So you can do `el[0]`, `el[1]` etc., but remember that `el` elements aren't jquery "objects", normally they are DOM elements, so you can't do `el[0].text("Hello")`. As in the `each` method, you have to do `$(el[0]).text("Hello");`

It's even wrong to do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $(something).length; i++) {
    // do something with el[i] or more often with $(el[i])
}
```

because in this way the `$(something)` will be recalculated every cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative methods to the each function, here are two:

## Setup

```
var $all = $('*');
var len = $all.length;
```

## 1

```
while(--len){
   // use $($all[len]); for jQuery obj
   var elem = $all[len];
   doWork(elem);
}
```

## 2

```
//reset len for next loop
len = $all.length;
do {
   var $elem = $all.filter(':eq('+ --len + ')');
   doWork($elem);
} while (len);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a for loop. look at 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: w3schools is a terrible resource. Use MDN instead. Also, please don't just point to an external resource and walk away. Include the link for reference and quote the relevant parts here. Also, just pointing to the language feature (even if you show the syntax) is hardly going to be useful here

Comment: also, it is not technically true that a `for` loop _has_ to be used. Among other options, there are `while` loops, `do-while` loops, recursion, asynchronous recursion, `setInterval`, or you can even hack something together from `eval` and string multiplicaion (via `join`s).

Comment: Referencing links must have context, So user can understand.